# Button only returns data on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to return the desired data:

```html
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" >Teste</button>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {

  $.getJSON('valreceber.php', function(data) {
    $.getJSON('valreceberext.php', function(data1) {
      $.getJSON('valreceberext1.php', function(data2) {
        $.getJSON('valreceberext2.php', function(data3) {
          $.getJSON('valreceberext3.php', function(data4) {
            $.getJSON('valreceberext4.php', function(data5) {

              var results = data.concat(data1).concat(data2).concat(data3).concat(data4).concat(data5);

              var arr = [];
              Object.keys(results).forEach(c => {

                id_utt1 = results[c].N_utente;

                arr.push(id_utt1);

              })

              $.getJSON('valreceber1.php?arr' + '&arr=' + arr, function(data6) {

                document.querySelector(".dad-pagamento").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);


                function clickHandler() {
                  data6.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a.N_utente - b.N_utente;
                  });

                  data6.forEach(function(person) {
                    var id = person.N_utente;
                    var filteredData = results.filter(d => d.N_utente === id);
                    addHtml(person.NomeResp, person.moradaResp, person.CodigoPostal, person.Localidade, filteredData);
                  });

                }

                function addHtml(NomeResp, moradaResp, CodigoPostal, Localidade, filteredData) {

                  var html = ``;

                  html += ``;

                  document.querySelector(".pagmfalta").innerHTML += html;
                  $('#minhaDiv1').show();

                }
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

At the level of expected result, it is working correctly.

What I have is a problem with the button that calls the function to return the data. For the data to be shown, I have to click the button twice and I wanted to click the button once to show the data coming from the database.

The reason for showing the data only on the second click is because of these lines:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function(){
```

and

```
document.querySelector(".dad-pagamento").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

How can I solve the problem for when clicking once on the button show the data soon?

Comment: Why do you add the event handler both with jQuery and with the native API?

Comment: if you already know why you need to click twice then why add an event handler twice?

Comment: @Chris G Because if you remove one of the handlers when clicking on the button it doesn't show any of the data. I wanted to have just one event handler and the code to show the data, but I'm not succeeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just have to invoke the handler manually, so that it piggy-backs on the first click:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {

  // ...

  function clickHandler() {
    ....
  }
  clickHandler(); // apply it once right away
  document.querySelector(".dad-pagamento").addEventListener("click", clickHandler); // set it as handler for later clicks

  // ...
});
```

(Note that I moved the line where the `clickHandler` is placed after its declaration - it works the other way too, but it is confusing)

Comment: change this code `document.querySelector(".dad-pagamento").addEventListener("click", clickHandler); function clickHandler() { data6.sort(function (a, b) { return a.N_utente - b.N_utente; });` 
for the code you added here to the answer and the rest of the code I kept, but it doesn't show the data that way

Comment: Yes, sorry, shouldn't have started changing your code. Have a look at the updated answer.